# Firebase functions (kotlin2js) error: cannot read property 'iterator' of undefined

Tags: javascript, kotlin, undefined, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing an Android app that stores data in a Firebase Firestore and manipulates it with Firebase Cloud Functions. I've written the server code using kotlin2js. The Cloud Function throws an undefined error when trying to iterate over the properties of a simple object.

Why am i getting this error?

How do I process the data stored in the object?

1) MainActivity.kt

```
    package com.srsly.wtf       

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.button        

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {        

        override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(bundle)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)        

            button.setOnClickListener { _ -> upload() }
        }        

        fun upload() {
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("test")
            .add(TestClass())
            .addOnSuccessListener { ref ->        

                ref.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ -> 
                    button.text = snapshot.toObject(TestClass::class.java).foo 
                }
            }
        }        

        data class TestClass(val foo = "bar")        

    }
```

2) index.kt

```
    import kotlin.js.Promise        

    external fun require(module: String): dynamic
    external val exports: dynamic        

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {        

        val functions = require("firebase-functions")
        val admin = require("firebase-admin")

        admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)        

        exports.receiveObj = functions.firestore.document("/test/{testId}").onWrite { event ->        

            val obj = event.data.data().unsafeCast<Map<String, String>>()        

            obj.entries.forEach{        

                val newObj = js("({})")
                newObj[it.key.toUpperCase()] = it.value.toUpperCase()        

                event.data.ref.set(newObj)
            }        

        }
    }
```

3) index.js

```
    (function (_, Kotlin) {
      'use strict';

      var Unit = Kotlin.kotlin.Unit;

      function main$lambda(event) {
        var obj = event.data.data();
        var tmp$;

        tmp$ = obj.entries.iterator();

        while (tmp$.hasNext()) {

          var element = tmp$.next();
          var newObj = {};

          newObj[element.key.toUpperCase()] = element.value.toUpperCase();

          event.data.ref.set(newObj);
        }

        return Unit;
      }

      function main(args) {

        var functions = require('firebase-functions');
        var admin = require('firebase-admin');

        admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

        exports.receiveObj = functions.firestore.document('/test/{testId}').onWrite(main$lambda);
      }

      _.main_kand9s$ = main;

      main([]);
      Kotlin.defineModule('index', _);

      return _;

    }(module.exports, require('kotlin')));
```

4) build.gradle for the functions project

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'        

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }        

    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'        

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'        

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8        

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }        

    dependencies {
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
        testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js:$kotlin_version"
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    }        

    compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
        moduleKind = "commonjs"
        outputFile = "functions/index.js"
    }
```

5) the error message from the firebase functions log

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'iterator' of undefined
        at main$lambda (/user_code/index.js:7:23)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
        at next (native)
        at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
        at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
        at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
        at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:695:26
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: Looks like `obj.entries` is undefined.